# PhpStorm freeze, slow indexing, loading folders

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using PhpStorm and recently it started to go extremely slow.
I've got 32GM RAM, for PhpStorm I gave him 15GB - still not helped.

- Folders are loading for ages
- Indexing takes forever
- Scanning files to index takes forever as well

I've got folders excluded, I've tried to look for solution on official forums but answers from IntelliJ are literally useless.

Also whenever I restart PhpStorm it starts indexing again.. ( All of these issues showed with installation with last update. )

**EDIT**
It shows up that it was due to last version update, I've just downgraded back to last 2019 and everything works.

Comment: You should file new issue ticket using their [issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?draftId=25-2759001) instead.

Comment: @Pantherax Emix is correct -- this kind of stuff should be reported to JetBrains Support -- either via command in `Help` menu or via `Submit a request` link on their forums: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731

Answer (score 5):

I am having the same experience. There seems to be a significant slowdown in the processing/indexing of PHAR files within vendor.

Answer (score 3):

on Windows:

```
File -> settings -> Directories
```

rightclick on folders and mark desired as `excluded` of indexing.

I did that for `bootstrap`, `vendor`(ohhh, heavy one), `.idea` (probably),`storage->framework->views`(cache, annoys when searching) and `node_modules`(heavy one).
**Reboot.**

Now it works sufficiently faster as well as it loads .

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to install `phpstan` package

```
composer require phpstan/phpstan --dev
```

and then exclude `vendor` folder from `phpstorm`